# OPencart Urls not working

Tags: opencart

I rewrite the login modules Url of Open Cart & fater Rewriting the url Login, Sign Up, & my account page is norking.

url :-https://www.gopromote.com.au/index.php?route=account/login

after rewriting Url
https://www.gopromote.com.au/login

Pls help me guys.

Comment: include the codes you tried

Comment: With all opencart urls u need to pass token which is defined in opencart url, checkout code in any in built controller you will get know about token.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that:
1. SEO url setting is ON in store back end.
2. mods_rewrite is enabled on your web server.